# Replace list comprehension with FK lookup

Tags: python, mysql, django

I currently have the following list comprehension:

```
[item.service.name for item in OrderItem.objects.all()]
```

`service` is a FK on `OrderItem`, so the above code is doing tons and tons of useless FK lookups. How would I get all `services` in a single query?

Answer (score 3):

The following will give you what you need:

```
OrderItem.objects.values_list('service__name', flat=True).distinct()
```